# Ruby on Rails Routing changes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Recently I've tried to update my routes to be more specific in the routing.rb file:

```
resources :users
match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
```

I removed the `resources :users` and changed the above to

```
match 'users/new' => 'users#new'
match 'users/show/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :users_show
match 'users/edit' => 'users#edit'

match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
```

But when I try to click on the same link that I've had before in my layout page using the signup_path (http://localhost:3000/signup), I get the following error:

undefined method `users_path' but I am not using users_path anywhere

Shouldn't it still work?  I haven't changed anything else in the other pages.  The controller and actions are still the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are missing a forward slash prefix to each `match 'user...` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it tells is that you don have helper method named "users_path", which is created by `resources` in routes.rb.

Check by yourself with `rake routes`, what you get with your example:

```
 users_new  /users/new.(:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
users_show  /users/show/:id(.:format)  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
users_edit  /users/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
```

(*and no, you don't need forward slash at the beginning of path*).

You defined only routes for some pages (show/new/edit), but you don't have path for index/create/update/destroy actions. Add `resource` back to routes.rb and check which routes it generates. Remember that by default your `match`-ed routes match all requests, not specific HTTP methods (like with `resource`). If you want to fully reassemble this behavior,  take a look at documentation (at http://api.rubyonrails.org search for "match") and `:via` parameter.

Also why do you want to remove resource, and add all paths by yourself? If you want to limit available routes, then there are `:only`/`:except` options, you can also pass block and add routes by yourself, just check documentation (at http://api.rubyonrails.org and search for "resources" - it's shame I no longer can get link to specific documentation page and from Rails documentation).

Comment: I wanted to get away from resources entirely in my code so even using :only/:except is not acceptable for my own code style.  All I want to keep are new, show, and edit actions. Can you please tell me what you mean by missing a "helper method"?  I don't have my code in front of me now, so I can't check, but does that I mean resources creates helper files as well?  Thanks

Comment: By helper method I mean that call to `resources` creates named method when application starts, which takes parameters and returns string pointing to specific controller/action on server. This method isn't in any of files, it's just created on the fly and added to your controllers and views (through included module with all named routes). You still can use old syntax for defining route: `{:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :id=>"3"}` in most places, of course if you have added that specific route to your application. But then you can't use `user_path(@user)` method - it just wasn't defined

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need route for index and create actions (it's just same path, but they are using different HTTP method: GET for index and POST for create, so you get only one method for both when you use `resources`, but there is distinction in routes based on method used), update (same as show, but uses PUT instead of GET) and destroy (same as show, but uses DELETE HTTP method). To use specific HTTP method, just add `:method => "PUT"` to your form_tag/form_for call, or link_to

Answer (score 2):

I think basicxman is on the right track. You need a leading '/' in all your routes

Change:

```
match 'users/new' => 'users#new'
match 'users/show/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :users_show
match 'users/edit' => 'users#edit'
```

To:
    match '/users/new' => 'users#new'
    match '/users/show/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :users_show
    match '/users/edit' => 'users#edit'

Also, do you still have the resources :users line at the top of your routes.rb? That'll also be necessary.

Comment: I don't have the resources :users anymore.  I wanted to remove it so I can be more specific

Comment: That makes sense; my head wasn't in the right place. ;) Did the leading slash resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a route to `create` action as well. Probably your signup form points to `users_path` with `POST` method which is basically the create action. So add to your routes the following

```
match 'users' => 'users#create', :via => :post, :as=>:users
```

For more customization info please see the [Rails routing guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)